# "Add a comment" does not look nice on a question with an active bounty

Tags: feature-request, design

Probably it's just me, but it doesn't look right to have an overlap between bounty banner and "add a comment" option. The later element seems to be lost on the page. [Here is the example question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720652/using-10-8-notification-center-in-java).

[image]

I've checked it on Chrome and Safari and for both browsers I've got the very same result.

Can we move it a bit lower?

Comment: @mehow true! It's sad to see that [this issue here for some 2 months](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233821/the-add-comment-link-and-comment-box-overlaps-bounty-box) and still not addressed.